# Need help editing a value in a list from a text file.

Tags: python

I am not able to add a number to my list that i have in a text file and don't know how to.

Code so far:

```
def add_player_points():
# Allows the user to add a points onto the players information.

    L = open("players.txt","r+")
    name = raw_input("\n\tPlease enter the name of the player whose points you wish to add: ")
    for line in L:
            s = line.strip()
            string = s.split(",")
            if name == string[0]:
                    opponent = raw_input("\n\t Enter the name of the opponent: ")
                    points = raw_input("\n\t Enter how many points you would like to add?: ")
                    new_points = string[5] + points
    L.close()
```

This is a sample of a key in the text file. There are about 100 in the file:

```
Joe,Bloggs,J.bloggs@anemailaddress.com,01269 512355, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                        ^
```

The value that i would like this number to be added to is the `0` besides the number already in there, indicated by an arrow below it. The text file is called `players.txt` as shown.

A full code answer would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to write a number to a text file? Or, maybe, do you want to build a list from numbers in a text file then add a number to the list?

Comment: All i want to do is allow the user to input a number into [5] of that value  and that number then saves into my text file. So, if the user wants to add +5 points. The number goes up 5 points

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the problem:

```
new_points = string[5] + points
```

You are adding a string with another string, you need to convert them to integer

```
new_points = int(string[5]) + int(points)
```

This is not checking for incorrect input, but assuming the file format is correct and the user input too, it should work.

Edit: If you want to update the file with the new information, a better way is to divide the problem in 3 parts: 1) Read player information into an appropriate data structure, e.g. a dictionary using the player name as key, 2) Make the changes into the dictionary, and finally 3) save the changes back to file. So your code should be split into 3 functions. Some help can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Ive made the change you recommended. The code runs as it should. It just doesn't edit the text file. I need to save the changes to the text file but this is the thing i dont know how to do.

Comment: There is nothing in your code (or your question) about editing the text file. That is more complicated: you can't simply edit in place. It would be easier to generate a new text file with the new values (read from old and write on new). It may be easier to read the whole file, into a dictionary indexed by user, then make the changes and finally write everything back to the file (so you keep the same file name).